# How to total calculated columns in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I created a custom list in SharePoint 2013.

I want to total calculated fields column

I searched the net there are blogs but for SharePoint 2010 not for SharePoint 2013

any help will be apprecaited

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to using the totals in a view, one easy way to achieve the same goal is to create a new number column and have a basic SPD workflow which sets the value of that number column to the calculated column. Have the workflow start on new and edit. Then, use that number column for the view with totals instead of the calculated column.

Answer (score 1):

To Total a **Calculated Column** you can not use the standard Totals in a View.

There are several options:

- Use a workflow to do the calculation mentioned before
- Change the XSLT which outputs the view; plenty of blogs around
- Add JavaScript to do the calculation after the View is displayed
- Add JavaScript **inside** a Calculated Column which does the totalling

There is a detailed step-by-step instruction for the last option at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create

Comment: Do you know some blogs who does this with JSOM API

Comment: You are on 2013, look for CSR/JSlink code examples, you have to write code that displays the Calculated value and for the last item displays the total calculated value.

Comment: Can you provide an example for calculated columns totaling using JSLink

Comment: I do not have or know of JSlink code which does totalling, I use the Calculated Column approach myself; see http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge there is no difference on creating calculated columns in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010. Most of the column types, fields, content types, etc. on SharePoint 2010 are still the same in 2013.

Here's a good reference guide:
http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/09/20/sharepoint-calculated-column-formulas/

Comment: I know the formula but I want to total a calculated field column how can I do that?

Comment: Where do you want to get the total in? Is this on a View with Groups?

Comment: Please see this: A+B store to C now I want to total this C