# how to add total sum for the row in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I see option to calculate total of the columns but not row.. I don't have access to sharepoint designer well.. is there anyway to do it through front-end..

Ex:
50 50 = 100 (I know this is possible) 
50
34
34
------
168 (not able to do this)[image]

Comment: seem that maybe you could also have a look at this other question - [How do I sum a column in SharePoint 2013](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146565/how-do-i-sum-a-column-in-sharepoint-2013/146633#146633)

Comment: that didn't help:(

Comment: Check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131111/how-to-total-calculated-columns-in-sharepoint-2013?rq=1, there are several options

Comment: You can use calculated column as Aziz has suggested in below answers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3` - **all numeric**.

To have a `Field4` that sums a **row**, use calculated column with `=SUM(...)` function.

To have a pseudo-row that sums a **column**, modify the view to enable totals.
*This will not work with calculated columns*.

Answer (score 0):

Update view and use the total option to sum the values in a column.

Comment: I tried that and not working as well?

Comment: Is project total a calculated field?

Comment: yes project total calculated, if you look at the screenshot the sum for project total not getting calculated

Comment: Ok in that case you need to use a workflow to put calculated value in a numeric field and use total on that field. Another option include using CSR or CSOM.

Comment: How do I use workflow?

Comment: Since you don't have access to SPD that is not an option. I posted that option for other users who are looking for similar solutions.

Comment: oh.. I tried CSR that isn't working either.. do you know any working version of CSR?

Answer (score -1):

In order to make a workflow I would recommend downloading sharepoint designer. Then load up the site you are trying to change and create a list workflow for the list you are trying to manipulate. Use workflow variables in a looping structure to loop through the columns in the row and sum the totals.